# Font Awesome not showing up in Dreamweaver 2018 Browser Live Preview

Tags: fonts, icons, font-awesome, dreamweaver

Does anybody know, why Font Awesome Icons are not showing up, when it comes to Dreamweaver 2018 Browser Live Preview?

Only the DW native webkit preview and IE11 are displaying them correctly. No Problems with that in DW 2017.

Until now no response from Adobe.

Answer (score 0):

You should use All.css file instead of fontawesome.css file